# Eclipse Files Not Found? Works with JCreator

Tags: java, eclipse, file, inputstream

Well I have these .java files in JCreator.

When I compile them in JCreator, it's fine, all files and folders are read and no errors occurred. But, I need to compile them in an Eclipse project to pass it to my professor. Then the problems started.

I added the .java files in a new Eclipse project and into a new package inside the

```
   src folder
```

Then after that, I made a new Folder in the project called

```
   res
```

and added it to the build path as a source Folder and added the files and folders in it.

```
   >Use as Source Folder
```

All sub-folders are fine same name and stuff, Refreshed the project a few times, checked the build path, but when I execute the program, It says:

```
   java.io.FileNotFoundException: sounds\bgmusic.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

from this line:

```
   InputStream test = new FileInputStream("sounds\bgmusic.wav");
```

Same folder name, same file, added it to the Build Path and stuff. Also, I repeat, It does not find ALL the files in the resource folder: Pictures, Sounds Fonts and other stuff. I already made some projects in Eclipse and I had successfully added pictures and sounds in them. But what's the problem with this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream ("sounds\bgmusic.wav");

I hope it resolves your issue.

You can also refer below link:

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077352/java-se/smartly-load-your-properties.html