# File found in Eclipse but not in Terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I've been having trouble getting my Java programs to run correctly in Terminal. For some reason, what happens when I compile and run the program in Eclipse breaks when I compile then run it in Terminal!

Specifically, there is a test .txt file I have saved in the parent folder for a Java project, and I'm trying to have my program read and print the files in the .txt file. **This works great in Eclipse, but when I run it in Terminal I get a NoSuchFileException even when I run it with the full file path.** (When I run it in Eclipse, I only need to type the name of the file, since it's in the parent folder, not even the full path.)

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

```
Here's what I tried:
```

First I attempted running the file as-is, the file I'm running is very simple at this point, as I'm still just trying to get it to run correctly:

Here is the file in case you want it:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{


    readFile();


    for (int i = 0 ; i < expressions.size(); i++){
        System.out.println(i + ".) " + expressions.get(i));
    }
    }


public static Object readFile() throws IOException{ 

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("File with expressions: ");
    String x = in.nextLine();


    //read all lines of a file into a List
    List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(x));


    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        expressions.add(list.get(i).toString());
    }
}
```

**In Terminal I ran:**

```
javac ConsoleCalculator.java
java ConsoleCalculator
```

**I got the correct response at first, Terminal printed:**

```
File with expressions:
```

and asked me for a file name, but whether i put a.txt or the full path of a.txt I always get a NoSuchFileException

I tried adding

```
        ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/a.txt");
```

to the main method as per the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819640/eclipse-files-not-found-works-with-jcreator) but it still isn't working.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: which lib you are using for Files class? or it is your custom class. If it is your custom class can you please provide code of Files class.

Comment: @atishshimpi I'm just using these libraries that come w/ java: import java.nio.file.Files; import java.nio.file.Paths;